# two-factor authentication suffix code in the password

Tags: multi-factor

In many sites where 2FA is enabled, the login flow is:

1. A form asking for username/password
2. If credentials are valid a new form asks for the verification code.

However, there are some implementations in where the verification codes are suffixed into the password so the flow is only a single form asking for `username` and `password+verification_code`.

Which approach offers better security?

Comment: Does the first example ask for a verification code only when the password is correct, or even for incorrect passwords?

Comment: Normally asks for the verification code only when credentials are valid, after some failed attempts a ”recaptcha” is shown

Comment: Password+verify might be more resistant against attackers checking for common or reused passwords then.

Comment: I think the suffix method has a slightly worse UX... Am I using the wrong password, or is my OTP mistyped/out of sync?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that a user has knowledge of its username, password (of course), and has access to its two-factor authentication (2FA) codes.

From the server end, having the `password+verification_code` in the same field will incur a slight overhead in extracting the password & code from each other, provided that we know that the code is the last 6~ digits of the entire string. We would have to decrypt it, split, check against the database, then permit the user. But I do see an upside to this, skipping one hop of user interaction and connection. Which means cutting the authentication period and communications to close to half.

Which to me seems like a convenience for the end-user, and what do they say about convenience? Especially when it comes to security.
**Convenience increases risk.**

> Which approach offers better security?

Well, when it comes to having two separate forms, one for *username/password* and the other for the *2FA Code*, this alone offers **segregation**, a distinct line between two different forms for different purposes. Having *segregations* are extremely valued in this field.

It is good practice for an implementation that will provide a different session or a unique token upon successful credentials being *POSTed*. This brings us to the next step, a new page/form that prompts the user for the 2FA code. This very practice is about sending **two pieces of key information separately**, one being something you know like your *username/password* and the other being something within your possession like a *2FA physical token* or an *authenticator app*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a measurable difference in security in the way 2fa is implemented from your examples.

In both cases the server receives username, password and unique 2fa token. In both cases an attacker would find it impossible to use a stolen password and login without the 2fa code.

Whilst having the 2fa form separate could appear appealing it has some pitfalls such as if 2fa token is only requested if the username and password combo is correct reveals if a password is correct, which could aid an attacker. But I digress.